# Why does the C# compiler authorize "throw ex" in catch, and is there a case where "throw ex" is useful?

Tags: c#, exception

In C#, younger developers use often "throw ex" instead of "throw" to throw exception to parent method.

Example :

```
try
{
    // do stuff that can fail
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // do stuff
    throw ex;
}
```

"throw ex" is a bad practise because  the stack trace is truncated below the method that failed. So it's more difficult to debug code. So the code must be :

```
try
{
    // do stuff that can fail
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // do stuff
    throw;
}
```

My question is why compilator authorize this  (or doesn't display a warning message ?) Is there a case which "throw ex" is useful ?

Comment: The compiler is not there to catch bad programming practices.

Comment: What about the occasions when `throw ex` is exactly what you want to do?

Comment: @jgauffin I think D Stanley's answer just did that for me...

Comment: More accurately, your question should be "why does the C# compiler not prevent you from using a particular construct (such as `throw ex`) in some locations" - to which the obvious answer is why should they spend time *specifically* changing the compiler to *prevent* this situation?

Comment: Wouldn't it be even more important to catch the truly difficult situation of empty `catch(Exception){}`?  Those can be a real devil to debug.  And yet, how annoying would it be if we couldn't ignore  `ThreadAbortException`?

Comment: Another thought after sitting on this for a day:  IMO `catch(){throw;}` is often bad practice as well since `finally{}` is generally more appropriate unless you absolutely need to know the details in the exception...  (In fact, I write a ton of finally clauses, but `catch` I use very sparingly)  Honestly, reviewing any largish volume of code, grepping `catch()` would be one of the first places I would look.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`throw new Exception();` or `throw ex;` both will use the same language rules to allow throwing an exception object, *(whether new or existing)*. When you want to add some extra information with the exception than that option is helpful.

See: How to: [Explicitly Throw Exceptions - MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xhcbs8fz(v=vs.110).aspx)

> You can explicitly throw an exception using the throw statement. You
>   can also throw a caught exception again using the throw statement.
>   **It is good coding practice to add information to an exception that is re-thrown to provide more information when debugging.**

Since both, `throw new Exception()` and `throw ex;` would require the same language rules, it is not really compiler's job to distinguish those  two.

Simply throwing the existing exception without any modification to the exception object would be using the same language construct.

Also as @D Stanley has pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24677797/961113), that truncating the stack trace could be the desired behaviour.

As far as your question about compiler not warning about it is concerned, It is not the job of compiler to warn about bad practices, there are code analysis tools. For example Managed Code Analysis tool will raise the warning for `throw ex;` [CA2200: Rethrow to preserve stack details](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182363.aspx)

Comment: That would be "wrapping" the exception in a new exception, not merely re-throwing the same (likely immutable) exception object.

Comment: @ebyrob, `throw new Exception` and `throw ex` would require the same language construct and I wasn't clear enough in explaining that in my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Why so many guesses about what the compiler can/can't do?  If it distinguishes between `if( x = 1 )` and `if( x == 1 )` for a warning, don't you think it could handle this case...  If it was worth pursuing?

Comment: @ebyrob, it is not a guess, `if(x=1)` and `if(x == 1)` is a different thing. `throw` on the other hand could receive an exception object. Now that exception object could be a new one or one that is caught.

Comment: @ebyrob, I have no idea where you are going with this argument `throw (Exception)(object)(x > 1);` is fine because throw accepts an expression returning exception object. *(Although it would en up with an exception at runtime)* but `if(x = 1)` would be an error since this expression doesn't return a `bool`. That is why they are different.

Comment: @Habib Sorry, obviously I've been writing C++ recently.  `if( b = true )` *is* valid, especially if `true` is substituted with a function call: `if( ret = WillThisSucceed() )` gives you a code block on success, and you don't throw away the return value.  It also comes with a warning that's probably about the same difficulty to implement as this case would be...  (And almost equally dubious in value)

Answer (score 15):

> Is there a case which "throw ex" is useful ?

Sure - sometimes you *want* to truncate the stack trace - to avoid exposing implementation details, etc.  Other times you may want to throw a *new* exception, which would mean the compiler would have to distinguish from just re-throwing the caught exception and throwing a new exception.

So why would you want the compiler to *prevent* you form doing something that 1) is not illegal and 2) could be useful?

Answer (score 1):

While compilers can certainly prevent some obvious programming errors, they cannot possibly watch out for best practices like that without triggering some inevitable false positives along the way.

Programmers could choose to change the content of the exception inside the exception handler, or throw a brand-new exception instead. In both cases a message that warns about throwing an exception from an exception handler would be annoying and useless.

One case when it make sense to change the internal state of an exception happens when you throw an exception from a recursive function. Consider a recursive descent parser reporting an error from several layers down the recursive chain. Each level of invocation could potentially add more useful information to an exception. However, wrapping exceptions of each subsequent layer into a new exception is not practical in this case, because you end up with a recursive data structure representing a flat list. One viable solution for situations like this would be creating a custom exception to which each catcher can add more details before re-throwing it. Since the function (or more precisely, a group of functions) is recursive, the location in code from which the original exception has been thrown is of less importance than the completeness of the context that lead to the exception in the first place.

It does not mean that finding situations like that is entirely useless: code proofing tools, such as ReSharper, can certainly help programmers watch out for issues like this. The compiler, however, is a poor choice for a best practice watchdog, because for the most part the compiler should do what it is told.

Comment: Out of curiosity, which exception classes are you using which allow you to change their internal state after construction?  (Exception chaining, mentioned in another answer, is the standard way to add extra information to a caught exception)

Comment: @ebyrob I edited the answer to give you an example from my relatively recent code. I've done this in other projects, too.

Comment: Instead of trying to reinvent the wheel, you could use the standard `AggregateException`: `http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.aggregateexception%28v=vs.110%29.aspx`.  Notice, this too, is immutable.  InnerExceptions can be filled in only at construction.  Note: catching 1 exception 100 times (whether recursive or not) is probably bad practice.  Better to catch at the very top level and keep around enough state to create a single useful description.

Comment: @ebyrob How is replacing a class that is mutable by design with an immutable class a "reinventing the wheel"? Certainly, one can build code around `AggregateException` to discard old instances and build new ones as you go, but that would be the same as simulating mutability by concatenating immutable strings. `AggregateException` is good for iterative situations, but it is not nearly as good for recursive situations.

Comment: which class is mutable by design again?  Clearly you're using exception classes you created yourself and you never answered my original question "which exception classes are you using?".  If they are self-made, name and class-hierarchy, or there's no way to even discuss it.  (I know you didn't write `System.Exception`, which, last I checked, is immutable, I'm guessing you might be sub-classing that one)

Comment: @ebyrob My exception class that I described in the third paragraph of the answer.

Comment: Okay, guess I was wrong... There is a `.Data` property on `Exception`:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.exception.data%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  This seems a lot more useful example than hand-waving about "recursion-hard" with no examples whatsoever.  The MSDN article even re-throws the `Exception` by name.

Comment: Writing an exception class is called "sub-classing".  Not "design".  Sheesh.  Promote user warnings/errors to a first-class object and leave exceptions for when the library developer screwed up why don't you?

Answer (score 0):

I guess I consider `catch` the culprit when you actually just want something to propagate up the stack.  Shouldn't `catch` be avoided entirely in favor of `finally`?

```
bool bSucceeded = false;
try
{
    // do stuff that can fail
    bSucceeded = true;
}
finally
{
    if( !bSucceeded ) 
        // do stuff you need to do only on error.  (rare, for me)

    // cleanup stuff (you're nearly always doing this anyways right?)
}
```

I've written many `bSucceded`'s, and don't think I have *ever* written `throw` inside `catch` without wrapping in a new Exception().  (At least since I was first learning Java in '99 or so.)

I'm guessing the massive number of possible ways to deal with this is why they let you do what you want here instead of trying to lock it down.